# Curly brace expansion with two arrays to make every combination

Tags: arrays, bash, curly-braces

I can use curly braces and the `..` to make combinations as follows:

```
$ echo {"foo","bar"}{1..2}
foo1 foo2 bar1 bar2
```

If I have two arrays `arr1=("foo" "bar")` and `arr2=(1 2)`, is it possible to achieve the same thing?

For example, something like:

```
$ echo ${arr1[@]}${arr2[@]}       # Returns "foo bar1 2"
or
$ echo {${arr1[@]}}{${arr2[@]}}   # Returns "{foo bar}{1 2}"
```

Comment: I hope you control the array's contents. If `arr1=( '$(rm -rf ~)' )`, the `eval`-based approach is not going to end well.

Comment: I'm getting a list of user home dirs from /etc/passwd and then grepping within a hard-coded array of files in each user dir. I think I have decided to just go with a for loop though... ;)

Comment: Then this makes a different question. With `grep` you can use `grep -f  <(printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}")` to grep for multiple patterns. Please don't ask XY question.

Comment: @KamilCuk, ...so, I *think* array1 in the use case described above is the list of home directories, and array2 is the list of filenames to search in all of those directories, so it's not necessarily an array of patterns they're trying to feed to grep. Which is to say -- yes, they should have described the use case, but I'm not sure that it's *that particular* XY question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brace `{1..2}` expansion happens before variable expansion, so it's not possible to do it that way without `eval`.

Just iterate over two arrays and create all possible combinations

```
for i in "${arr1[@]}"; do
   for j in "${arr2[@]}"; do
      echo "$i$j"
    done
done
```

Or you can use `eval`. To do this safely, use `printf %q` to generate safely-quoted versions of your array contents, like so:

```
printf -v arr1_str '%q,' "${arr1[@]}"; arr1_str=${arr1_str%,}
printf -v arr2_str '%q,' "${arr2[@]}"; arr2_str=${arr2_str%,}
eval "printf '%s\n' {${arr1_str}}{${arr2_str}}"
```

...which you can see working (with some intentionally hostile/tricky sample data) at https://ideone.com/HunmC3

Comment: Ah, eval is what I was looking for. Why is that "evil"?

Comment: It's just one letter away from eval. [Eval and security issues](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: @WarBro, see [BashFAQ #48](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048). Not paying attention when using `eval` often means that filename fragments can be executed as code, or that other Bad Things happen.

Comment: ...that's true here, btw. `"${arr1[*]}"` is **completely** unsafe substituted into `eval`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, would you accept an edit that used `printf %q` to substitute an `eval`-safe result?

Comment: Och, good idea, sure. That still will break if one of array elements would have `,` (or not?).

Comment: ...so, for comparison's sake, first the current approach: https://ideone.com/WmTUNU -- and then the proposal: https://ideone.com/HunmC3. BTW, note that commas work fine in the proposal. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do exactly what you asked for with GNU parallel:

```
parallel echo {} ::: "${arr1[@]}" ::: "${arr2[@]}"
```

(if you want the output on one line, you can pipe the output into `tr -s "\n" " "`: `parallel echo {} ::: "${arr1[@]}" ::: "${arr2[@]}" | tr -s "\n" " "`